# pdftotext output different on Windows 7 PC and linux server, why?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-12.04, pdftotext

I am using the same version of xpdf on both machines.  However, the .txt file created on the Windows 7 PC is different than that created on the Ubuntu 12.04 linux server.  The Windows 7 .txt file is well formed with numerous line breaks that makes parsing fairly easy.  However, the linux version doesn't contain any line breaks at all.  Are there options that pdftotext on Windows 7 uses that I need to explicitly call when running on linux?

Answer (score 2):

From reading the following http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext man page I see the following:

```
-eol unix | dos | mac
```

Can you try execute with the following flags and see if this resolves the issue:

```
pdftotext -eol dos
```